# Reusing .constant in definition of another .constant

Tags: angularjs

I would like to use a constant (`general_config`) as an argument to create another constant (`first_config`) in Angular.

```
angular.module('app.config', [])

   .constant('general_config', { server_url: "someurl.com" })

   .constant('first_config', { url: general_config.server_url + "/path" })
```

But this results in "general_config is not defined".

Is it possible?

Comment: This was a very poorly written question. I rewrote it from scratch. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask better questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in a variable and then use that variable for both constants. I used an IIFE to prevent adding the variable to the global scope:

```
(function() {
  var serverUrl = "someurl.com";
  angular.module('app.config', [])
    .constant('general_config', { server_url: serverUrl })
    .constant('first_config', { url: serverUrl + "/path" });
})();
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YG3yOkLXcPyIGNvizDXS?p=preview)

John Papa has some great information about IIFE's in his [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#iife).